# no python output using print

Tags: python, csv, printing, output

Hi am new to python and just trying to read a simple csv file and output to the terminal using:

```
import csv
with open('cancerdata.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
     for row in data:
         print row
```

However when I run:

```
python program.py
```

I get no output, yet no errors.

What simple noob error have I made?

Comment: Your file is probably empty; if you add a `print 'test'` line before and after the `for` loop, does it print `test` twice?

Comment: I'd also ask what the output of `head cancerdata.csv` is, run from wherever you are running `python program.py`.

Comment: It may be easier to debug this in an IPython interactive session than via a script.

Comment: hmm pycharm IDE is saying end of statement expected when hovering over print...

Comment: @ adding print 'test' both before and after the for loop only prints out the first call to print.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments it's *very likely* that your `cancerdata.csv` file is **empty**. See:

```
$ touch cancerdata.csv
$ python myprogram.py
```

*No output*.

```
$ echo "1,2,3\n" > cancerdata.csv
$ echo "3,4,5\n" > cancerdata.csv
$ python myprogram.py
['3,4,5\\n']
```

**We have output!**

Comment: hi it's definitely not empty

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the [Dialects and Formatting Parameters](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params) section of the CSV documentation. Maybe there is a quotechar type that is not expected or something similar? (just a guess).